# Efficient string matching for multiple patterns

Tags: python, python-re

**The Problem**

I have a single long text and many sentences.
I want to find the positions of the sentences in the text.
If it is found many times in the text I want to know all of the positions.
I want to match the sentence even if there are many whitespaces between each word.

**For Example**

text = "This is a sample text, this is my query"
query = ["this is my query", "this is a another query"]

Answer: [(query_0_positions), (no_positions_for_query_1)]

**My Current Solution**

I use python `re` module in the following way:

1. I compile the query pattern with \s* in between the words - example: this\s*is\s*my\s*query
2. Use finditer on the text and iterate the matches

**Python Code Example**

```
import re
text = 'This is a sample text, this is my query'
queries = ['this is my query', 'this is a another query'] 
for query in queries:
    query = re.sub(r'\\ ', "\s*", re.escape(query))
    pattern = re.compile(query, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

    matches = pattern.finditer(text)
    # Do somthing with the matches
```

**The Issue**

This can be very slow when the are many queries and a long text.

Is there any algorithmic idea or implementation that can help me achieve this same functionality while being more efficient?

Comment: Why not compile the regex before the ```for-loop```?

Comment: Because for every query the pattern is different

Comment: Just thinking aloud here... (a) if spaces are irrelevant, you are basically looking for subsequences in a list of words, and (b) maybe you can find the positions/indices in that list where each word appears, then check where the words in the queries appear at consecutive indices.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really works for your usecase, but if whitespaces are irrelevant, you can convert your text to a list of words, then get the indices of those words in the list. Then, for each query, get the positions in the text for each word in the query, offset by the position of the word in the query itself, and get the intersection of those sets. Those will be the starting indices in the list of word, what can then be translated back to the positions in the original text.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce

text = 'This is a sample text, this is my query'
queries = ['this is my query', 'this is a another query'] 

text_list = text.lower().split()
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'text,', 'this', 'is', 'my', 'query']

indices = defaultdict(list)
for i, w in enumerate(text_list):
    indices[w].append(i)
# {'this': [0, 5], 'is': [1, 6], 'a': [2], 'sample': [3], 'text,': [4], 'my': [7], 'query': [8]})

for query in queries:
    words = query.lower().split()
    pos = reduce(set.intersection, ({i - k for i in indices[w]} for k, w in enumerate(words)))
    print(query, pos)

# this is my query {5}
# this is a another query set()
```

Of course, this only works if the query is composed of whole words, not if it itself is a regex, or supposed to start or end with a partial word.
Punctuation *might* be a problem. If it is relevant for the queries, you should leave it in, but then a query ending just before punctuation might not be found. The best way might be to treat punctuation as words, too, using `re.split` with `\b`, i.e.

```
text_list = [w for w in re.split(r"\b", text.lower()) if w.strip()]
```

The complexity of this is... difficult. Probably something like O(C+W) for creating the index (C and W being number of chars and words in the text), then O(QC+QW*A) for each query (QC, QW and A being chars and words in the query and Average number of occurances of the words in the text).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `query` prep for use inside a regex is not quite correct (the `"\s*"` replacement is wrong, it must be set with a *raw* string literal) and a bit inefficient in case of consecutive spaces. You need to use

```py
query = re.sub(r'(?:\\\s)+', r"\\s*", re.escape(query))
```

This will replace one or more escaped whitespaces with a single `\s*`  pattern.

Unfortunately, with `re`, there is little left for optimization. However, if you `pip install regex`, and then use `import regex as re`, you can get the regex part of the code work faster, as the PyPi `regex` library is more stable when working with complex regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to dive a bit deeper into natural language processing, I can recommend [spaCy](https://spacy.io/), which is a full-fledged NLP library that includes, among other things, a pattern matcher with a rather flexible and powerful API.

###### Preparing the document

After installing spaCy, documents need to be processed first.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', 
                 exclude=['ner', 'parser'] # you probably don't need named entities and syntactic structure
                )

text = 'This is a sample text, this is my query'
queries = ['this is my query', 'this is a another query']

# the tokenized, lemmatized, parts-of-speech-tagged document
doc = nlp(text)
```

The `doc` includes all words from your document. Let's take a look at the tokens:

```py
>>> print(' '.join(f'{tok.text}/{tok.lemma_}/{tok.pos_}' for tok in doc))
This/this/DET is/be/VERB a/a/DET sample/sample/NOUN text/text/NOUN ,/,/PUNCT this/this/DET is/be/VERB my/my/PRON query/query/NOUN
```

What's cool about spaCy is that it keeps track of the character offset in the original document (`tok.idx`) and trailing whitespace (`tok.whitespace_`), so you can always map to and reconstruct the original document if you need to ([docs](https://spacy.io/api/token)).

###### Pattern matching

The pattern matcher takes lists of property dictionaries. For example, your first query needs to be translated into:

```py
[{'TEXT': 'this'}, {'TEXT': 'is'}, {'TEXT': 'my'}, {'TEXT': 'query'}]
```

You can define all kinds of properties, like parts of speech, punctuation, case-insensitive matches, lemma search, etc. (see [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) for more info)

Thus, one way to search for your patterns would be

```py
# initialize the matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

for i,q in enumerate(queries, start=1):
    pattern = [{'TEXT': word} for word in q.split()]
    matcher.add(f"query{i}", [pattern])

# find the matches
matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

The output is `query1 6 10 this is my query`.